# Is it possible to "fire and forget" a request with pymongo

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, pymongo

For example in a tornado application, i would like to remove an element, but i don't care about the result of the remove.

Is it possible to use pymongo that way :

```
import pymongo
db=pymongo.connection()['mydb']
class assassin(RequestHandler):
    get(self):
        id=self.get_argument('id')
        self.write('delete send')
        db['personne'].remove({'_id':ObjectId(id)}
```

Comment: I believe you can add another param to the `remove` of `{'w':0}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sammaye alludes to, you can disable all write acknowledgement via the "write concern" option to [`remove`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.remove) which makes it fire-and-forget:

```py
db['personne'].remove({'_id':ObjectId(id)}, w=0)
```

Comment: looks like write concern default was 0 in earlier version, then 1 http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/drivers-write-concern/